# Keep from seeing everything a friend posts

Tags: facebook

I want to restrict a friend on Facebook from *me* being able to see everything they post, but they can still see what I post on my Timeline. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribing from that friend should prevent you from seeing any further updates.